# where to keep images in heroku for using it in csv in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, paperclip

I have a csv file to be imported to database in heroku and the csv contains image names and i have to place the images in a folder and specify its path in the import code. So i have tried keeping the images in the public folder and assets folder and it returned error as follows

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - /images/picture17.jpg):
```

I have even set true in production.rb as follows

```
 config.serve_static_assets = true
```

but still i get the error. please help me.

EDIT:

```
csv_text = File.read('sample.csv')
        csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
        csv.each do |row|
            Model.create!({"name"=>row['name'], "age"=>row['age'], "pic"=>File.open("/images" + row['pic_name'])})
        end
```

Comment: You need to give us more details - paste the import code.

Comment: I have posted the import code in edit

Answer (score 0):

When on a free plan Heroku deletes your public/assets directory at a certain interval

(I guess once a day.) therefor you should serve the assets through the asset pipeline which has been integrated in Rails since 3.1+

Although you mention you are importing a CSV file which makes me guess there is actually a database set up for this application.

Let me introduce you to the sweet life of CarrierWave combined with Cloudinary.

Take the time to read the CarrierWave documentation: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave

And the Cloudinary documentation: http://cloudinary.com/documentation

Here comes the good part:
Heroku actually integrates with cloudinary pretty neat https://addons.heroku.com/cloudinary

simply include the Cloudinary::CarrierWave header in your uploader and this should do the trick!